# How to pass variables in sqlplus in bash command

Tags: bash, parameters, sqlplus

Here is may problem : I have inline sqlplus call in my bash file and I would like to pass it a parameter

this code is what I'm trying

```
c_id=`sqlplus -S $login/$password  $id << EOF
    set pagesize 0
    set verify off
    set head off
    set feedback off
    SELECT id from bdd.table where ID not in (select id from bdd.TMP_table) and id > &1 and ROWNUM <= 1000 order by id;
    exit;
    EOF`
```

how can I use my $id parameter in my where statement (&1)?

Answer (score 8):

Just change `&1` to `$id`. For example:

```
id=101
c_id=`sqlplus -S $login/$password  << EOF
    set pagesize 0
    set verify off
    set head off
    set feedback off
    SELECT id from bdd.table where ID not in (select id from bdd.TMP_table) and id > $id and ROWNUM <= 1000 order by id;
    exit;
    EOF`
```

Bash will perform parameter substitution. `$id` will be substituted with the actual value of the parameter i.e. `101` in this case, before `sqlplus` runs.

Comment: Thank you it was that ! I realised it's what I did at the beging but i had mistakes on my loop...

Comment: @Shellter : I would to do this but it requires 15 points of reputation to me to enable this action :s I will do this later so ...